# html-css- Custom font won't load on first display

Tags: html, css, fonts

this is my code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "BYekan";
src: url(fonts/Yekan.eot);
src: url(fonts/Yekan.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(fonts/Yekan.woff) format("woff"), url(fonts/Yekan.ttf) format("truetype"), url(fonts/Yekan.svg#BYekan) format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal
   }

   body{
    font-family: BYekan,'BYekan',tahoma,Arial;
    font-size: 12.5px;
    }
```

these are the codes on the top of my css file . it's very strange , every time I visit my website, the custom font won't load but when I change into another page , then the font loads and will be displayed with my custom font .

Could you help me . 
How can I display the custom font everytime I visit my website?

Comment: Show us your website or some code to different pages

Comment: Show a complete testable demo that reproduces the problem and identify the origin of the font and the way used to generate the font files.